# Angles between two 3D Points

Tags: matrix, vector, euler-angles

I'am searching for a mathematical matrix method that can determine the xyz-angle of a line

The line starts at (0,0,0) and end (2,3,4)

I Found a lot about euler's rotation matrix but that is between two vectors, I only have two points.

I googled for some while now, but nothing specfic for my problem. After that I started using my old schoolbooks and begun from scratch. But I failed so far.

Someone a good source where I can start solving such problems ?

Comment: There are multiple misconceptions here. First: a line doesn't start or end - it is infinite. You are talking about a line segment. Second: there are no angle between two points. You can calculate angle between two vectors.

Comment: Thanks, I understand.

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15101103/euler-angles-between-two-3d-vectors