# Having labels of 3d objects facing camera

Tags: javafx, javafx-3d

I have created a 3d stellar charting system (takes in an astrographic star map like Simbad or Hipparcos3 and draws stars in an x,y,z coordinate system based on RA, dec and parallax).
It works fairly well and I can rotate the entire 3d star map by manipulating the camera (using the mose).
I have attached labels to each star for identification. Now as I rotate the star map, the labels become unintelligible as they turn.
Is there a way to have the labels always face the viewing plane of the camera? So as I turn the 3d map, the labels are flat to my viewing camera.

Comment: Possibly related to [Calculate rotations to look at a 3D point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251828/calculate-rotations-to-look-at-a-3d-point)

Comment: You can check the answer to [How to get 2D coordinates on window for 3D object in javafx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52017893/how-to-get-2d-coordinates-on-window-for-3d-object-in-javafx/52020701#52020701) (mainly the edited part)

Comment: thanks, I will check these out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had forgotten I asked this question and a year and a half later, I picked up the problem and managed to solve it.

I found this old question just a day ago.

The answer is located here: [Getting the initial position and rotation of a scene in Javafx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64407336/getting-the-initial-position-and-rotation-of-a-scene-in-javafx)